# Stuck with sidebar registering

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I tried to add a custom page to my Wordpress template. That part is good. What I´m stuck with is a common sidebar that appears although I registered a custom sidebar for it.

I am calling the sidebar...

```
<?php get_sidebar('dfth'); ?>
```

And registering sidebar (below there is default sidebars registered also)

```
function web2feel_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(

    'name' => __( 'Sidebar', 'web2feel' ),

    'id' => 'sidebar-1',

    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</aside>',

    'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',

    'after_title' => '</h1>',

) );

    register_sidebar(array(

    'name' => 'Footer',

    'before_widget' => '<li class="botwid grid_2 %2$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</li>',

    'before_title' => '<h3 class="bothead">',

    'after_title' => '</h3>',

));     

        register_sidebar( array(

    'name' => __( 'Throwers ),

    'id' => 'dfth',

    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</aside>',

    'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',

    'after_title' => '</h1>',

) );



}

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'web2feel_widgets_init' );
```

I just don´t get what´s happening, everything seems to be okay but sidebar still doesn´t come up. I get an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE in /data01/virt30509/domeenid/www.throwholics.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Underfire/functions.php on line 1`Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_sidebar('dfth')` looks for a `sidebar-dfth.php` file in your template directory. If not found, it loads the default sidebar. To call the sidebar you registered in a template, use e.g.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'dfth' ) ) : ?>
<div class="first dfth-widgets">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'dfth' ); ?>
</div><!-- .first -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'dfth' ) ) : ?>
<div class="first dfth-widgets">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'dfth' ); ?>
</div><!-- .first -->
<?php endif; ?>`

Thats the sidebar template right?

Comment: dynamic_sidebar() calls each of the active widget callbacks in order, which prints the markup for the sidebar (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).